# Can't get jQuery Datatables in Meteor to work

Tags: meteor, datatables

Unfortunately I'm completely lost when trying to implement jQuery DataTables in Meteor. The documentation for the Meteor version is non-existent and the examples it gives don't make sense to me and don't follow the Discover Meteor book's application structure (ie. What the heck is `Template.myTemplateName.browsers` ? `.browsers`? I know `.rendered`, `.created`, `.helpers`, etc. Where the heck did `.browsers` come from?

I did `meteor create`, `mrt add iron-router`, `mrt add jquery-datatables`

Nothing gets displayed on the page with the following files. (the route's working but I get a Spacebars error).

I have a pre-defined `Services` collection with title, description, and sku

**Client:**

`index.html`

```
<template name="index">

<h1>Hello</h1>

{{> DataTable services }}

</template>
```

`index.coffee`

```
Template.index.services = -> return {

  # ## Id
  #   * While not required, setting a unique table id makes external manipulation possible through jquery
  id: "my-unique-table-id"

  # ## Columns
  #   * Map your dataset to columns you want displayed
  columns: [{
    title: "Title"
    data: "title"
  },{
    title: "Description"
    data: "description"
  },{
    title: "SKU"
    data: "sku"
  }]

  # ## Subscription
  #   * the datatables publication providing the data on the server
  subscription: "services"

  # ## Query
  #   * the initial client filter on the dataset
  query:
    grade: "A"
}
```

**Server**

`datatables.coffee`

```
if Meteor.isServer
  ServicesTable = new DataTableComponent
    subscription: "services"
    collection: Services

  ServicesTable.publish()
```

Comment: Do you possibly have your project (or a test project) uploaded somewhere like GitHub?

Comment: Hey, sorry, it's a private project at the moment. What I ended up doing is just going with another package - Reactive Tables. I got it up and running in about 5 minutes with the examples Reactive Tables provided.

Comment: Understand about the private project. In those cases, sometimes it is helpful to throw together a bare bones example to see if that helps locate the issue. Glad to hear you got something working with a different package.

Comment: I have the same problem. I know that 'browsers' is just a helper function. It was returning a JSON for DataTables. I really want to use {{> DataTables arg}} and without coffee. I have to resort to JQuery $('#tableEx').DataTable({...}); which is Meteor blasphemy.